# CSS to align LI

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of couples (name, value) and I would like to display them vertically aligned as in a table:

```
aaaaaaaa    first_value
bbbb        second_value
ccc         third_value
ddd         fourth_value
```

Is there a way to do so in HTML/CSS, without using tables (I suppose I should use UL/LI tags in some way)?

Comment: A good start is provided in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110389/little-problem-with-styling-dl

Comment: Creating table replicas with pure CSS is not that easy however if the data you are displaying is actually tabular by type you don't have to worry about not using tables to display them. Tables still have their purpose when displaying tabular data they are just a bad solution to create page layouts.

Comment: Would you please make it clear whether or not you have existing markup you need this to work with? Your title says "CSS to align LI", does this mean you're working with a `<ul>` or `<ol>`?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I started the question thinking about LIs but then I turned into a more general issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. Use a definition list.

```
<dl>
  <dt>aaa</dt>
  <dd>111</dd>

  <dt>bbb</dt>
  <dd>222</dd>

  <dt>ccc</dt>
  <dd>333</dd>
</dl>
```

and then

```
<style>
    dl dt { width: 100px; float: left; }
    dl dd { margin-bottom: 10px; }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wr6wL/

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! I did't even remember about those tags!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a [definition list](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) to me:

```
<dl>
    <dt>aaaaaaaa</dt>
    <dd>first_value</dd>

    <dt>bbbb</dt>
    <dd>second_value</dd>

    <dt>ccc</dt>
    <dd>third_value</dd>

    <dt>ddd</dt>
    <dd>fourth_value</dd>
</dl>
```

Some CSS to style it is in a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110389/little-problem-with-styling-dl).

Answer (score 1):

```
.name { display: inline-block; width: 100px }
```

Do consider using a table though if you have tabular data. That's what tables were made for.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do it with just CSS, but why not use a table? This is a perfectly valid use of one.

That said, an example with just CSS:

```
<ul>
    <li><div>name</div><div>value</div></li>
</ul>



li {overflow: auto;}
li div {width: 50%; float: left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this :

```
   <ul>
        <li><span class="fixedWidth">aaaaaaaa</span>first_value
        <li><span class="fixedWidth">bbbb</span>second_value
        <li><span class="fixedWidth">ccc</span>third_value
        <li><span class="fixedWidth">ddd</span>fourth_value
   </ul>
```

in your css add

```
.fixedWidth { display: inline-block; width: 100px }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a group of div tags](http://linuxandfriends.com/2009/04/04/how-to-style-div-elements-as-tables/) that have a table style.

Create your html divs like so:

```
<div class="div-table">
<div class="div-table-caption">This is a caption</div>
<div class="div-table-row">
<div class="div-table-col">1st Column</div>
<div class="div-table-col">2nd Column</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then you can add css styling to get the look you want:

```
.div-table{display:table; border:1px solid #003399;}

.div-table-caption{display:table-caption; background:#009999;}

.div-table-row{display:table-row;}

.div-table-col{display:table-cell; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #003399
```

View this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktraff/rwgYW/) for the end result.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="row">
        <p class="cell">aaaaaa</p><p class="cell">first_value</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="cell">bbbb</p><p class="cell">second_value</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="cell">ccc</p><p class="cell">third_value</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p class="cell">ddd</p><p class="cell">fourth_value</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{display:table;}
.row{display:table-row;}
.cell{display:table-cell; padding:10px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/cHhTE/

Comment: Using `<p>` tags for data this way does not seem right. You would probably be better off with a table in the first place, or at least a definition list.

Comment: @Wesley Murch.  Fair enough.  I think this is probably tabular data anyway... but I was responding to the OP's request for a way to do it without `table`s.

Comment: Sure sure, this just is not the kind of example we want to be teaching noobs. Just noticed the question title says "LI" as well... I guess OP wants to use a list? Very vague question.